# Как вызвать файл в "ожидаемое время"?

Tags: windows, rust

Сегодня я решил попрактиковаться в создании приложений с библиотекой windows-rs. Но вот незадача, запуская программу получаю ошибку "метод вызван в неожиданное время". В чем проблема?

по коду:

ошибка:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { code: 0x8000000E, message: Метод вызван в неожиданное время. }', src\main.rs:8:54
stack backtrace:
   0: std::panicking::begin_panic_handler
         at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:584 
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
         at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c\/library\core\src\panicking.rs:143
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
         at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c\/library\core\src\result.rs:1749
   3: enum$<core::result::Result<windows::Windows::Storage::StorageFile,windows::core::error::Error> >::unwrap<windows::Windows::Storage::StorageFile,windows::core::error::Error>
         at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c\library\core\src\result.rs:1065
   4: FileProperties::main
         at .\src\main.rs:8
   5: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once<void (*)(),tuple$<> >
         at /rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c\library\core\src\ops\function.rs:227
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\FileProperties.exe` (exit code: 101)
```

abc - путь к файлу

getfile,file - получаем файл

filet - тип файла

stri - переводим тип HSTRING в String

main.rs

```
use windows::Storage::*;
use windows::Foundation::*;
use windows::core::HSTRING;
fn main(){
    
    let abc:&str = r"///filepath\\\";
    let getfile = StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(&HSTRING::from(abc)).unwrap();
    let file = IAsyncOperation::GetResults(&getfile).unwrap();
    let filet = StorageFile::FileType(&file).unwrap();
    let stri = HSTRING::to_string_lossy(&filet);
    println!("{stri}")
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "FileProperties"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]


[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.39.0"
features = [
    "Storage",
    "Storage_FileProperties",
    "Storage_BulkAccess",
    "Storage_Search",
    "Foundation",
]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: возможно, `IAsyncOperation` предполагает, что візівать можно только из async/await рантайма. А подробней - нужно смотреть код.